# Is possible to avoid properties repetition without using mixins?

Tags: css, sass

How can avoid properties repetition?.

I have created a mixin with the color as a parameter (is the only property that changes). Is there another way to refactor this without using mixins?

```
td.animal-table__cell {
  &.animalType {
    &.mammal span::before {
      content: ' ';
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    &.reptile span::before {
      content: ' ';
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: green;
    }

    &.bird span::before {
      content: ' ';
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: purple;
    }

    &.others span::before {
      content: ' ';
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused-- I don't see any mixin here.  Are we looking at the desired output here?

Comment: In `less` you can add the following: `&.mammal span::before,&.reptile span::before,&.bird span::before, &.others span::before { content: ' ' ;.... }` and then you can combine the same styles together (`content`, `width`, `height` and `border-radius`) - Add it before the inner `&.mammal span::before {` line, and remove those styles from the all the rest  (I don't know `sass` syntax that well, that's why I didn't post it as an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerate with commas to group common styles:

```
td.animal-table__cell {
    &.animalType {
        &.mammal, &.reptile, &.bird, &.others {
            span::before {
                content: ' ';
                width: 6px;
                height: 6px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
        }
        &.mammal span::before {
            background-color: red;
        }
        &.reptile span::before {
            background-color: green;
        }
        &.bird span::before {
            background-color: purple;
        }
        &.others span::before {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    }
}
```

You can even get rid of the list and put `span::before` directly into `&.animalType` if you know you will have these styles on the nested span no matter what.